# Electrolytic rust removal

Tags: electrolysis

I'm currently removing rust on some bike parts so decided to use electrolysis. It's working fine, but the solution has turned a deep/dark blue whilst in most online videos it turns orange with the rust. My sacrificial anodes aren't stainless or chromed, and I dont believe they're galvanized either.

Is the blue colour any cause for concern (am I making anything toxic accidentally)?

Comment: Probably just copper and/or nickel from the metal parts. I wouldn't be concerned but of course use gloves and proper PPE. Never touch or mess with something whose identity you're not confident of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your anode/cathode are from copper, then the blue chemical in the solution is copper chloride (**CuCl2**).  Copper chloride can be toxic. So you should have safety equipment.

As for rust removal in general, I'd recommend you to use Citric acid (Squeezing lemons for the lemon juice isn't efficient since it will contain 5-6% Citric acid - so its better to buy powdered Citric acid from a store).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using citric acid
Burn it with blowtorch later so it does not get rust.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Probably not.

However, it's *always* prudent to follow proper safety procedures when doing ANYTHING with chemicals. Given you're doing something with electrolysis, there's probably an acid involved, or, if not, some kind of ionic solution. If you're using an acid, I'd recommend keeping a neutralizer (baking soda) on hand, as well as wearing rubber gloves and some kind of goggles. A rubber apron would also be recommended, although, not everybody owns one of those. (And, to be fair, if you did, you'd look a little suspicious.)

However! Please list the specific metals and solutions you're using in this process. It'd help greatly in determining whether you're in any danger.